# Inverse of $1/ \sin z $ as power series confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

This post shows [laurent series of $(\sin z) ^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648923/calculate-laurent-series-for-1-sinz) using the *Cauchy Product.* I have seen many compute thisby applying this argument $\frac{1}{1 - (z^3/3!-z^5/5^1+...)} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (z^3/3! -z^5/5^+...)^k$.

Can this be rigorously justified? 
(a) Can we rearrange the terms? 
(b) Is this still the inverse of $\sin z$?

---

**I believe these are the steps.** Replacing the terms given by $a_{n}$:

**(i)** We begin with $\sum _m ( \sum_n a_n )^m $.  As $\sum_n |a_n| < \infty$ by hypothesis.  From [Cauchy's Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), $(\sum_n a_n)^m = \sum_{n} b_{mn}$  and $ \sum_n |b_{mn}| < \infty$. Thus, $\sum_m \sum_n |b_{mn}| < \infty$.

**(ii)** By [rearrangment of positive series (Tonellis)](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf), $\sum_m \sum_n |b_{m,n}| = \sum_{m,n} |b_{mn}| = \sum_{k} |b_{f(k)}| < \infty$

**(iii)** Absolute convergence [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) $\sum_k b_{f(k)} = \sum_{m} \sum_n b_{mn} < \infty$. The power series has radius of convergence $\ge $ the radius of which $\sum a_n$ converges ($a_n$ is function of $z^n$) with $|\sum a_n | <1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side of your expansion starts with $1$ instead of $z$, but if you proceed as in robjohn's answer to the linked question, you have
$$
\sin z = z\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!},
$$
so that the series
$$
\frac{1}{\sin z} = \frac{1}{z} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}}
= \frac{1}{z} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\biggr)^{n}
$$
converges absolutely in the largest disk about $0$ such that $\left|\frac{\sin z}{z} - 1\right| < 1$, and so can be rearranged.

Comment: May you elaborate the details on why it can be rearranged - we are taking powers of power series? I believe we first apply Cauchy Product in the terms, then apply this theorem: https://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m500f09/Rearrangements.pdf  , is this right?

Comment: The important thing is, the double series is absolutely convergent, see for example [Rearrangement of double infinite sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532266). (If you like, pick an arbitrary bijection from $\mathbf{N} \times \mathbf{N}$ to $\mathbf{N}$ to arrange the terms in a single absolutely convergent sequence, then apply the theorem you linked.)

Comment: I have updated the post; and I believe the argument is correct,  what do you think?

Comment: Yes, that looks right. :)